# Can someone please help me understand Adobe After Effects Roto Brush 2 Propagation?

Tags: after-effects

I am new to the Roto Brush (saw it on Corridor Crew!) and for the most part have it working.

As I understand it, you roto out your first frame, then go through frame by frame tidying it up as required.

What I don't understand, is why on every subsequent frame, when I make a change, it propagates EVERY frame from my original frame forward to the one I just changed. Surely nothing should be changing in the earlier frames as I was happy with those?

Every change propagating every frame since frame 1 is taking aaages as I progress.

I don't actually have to make any changes for the propagation to go through every frame again. I only have to go back one or two frames to check something and it goes off on its little propagation run again.

Am I doing something wrong?